# Add a decimal point 2 chars from the right under PHP

Tags: php, decimal, point

I have a big array containing lots of elements containing numerical data.

Example:

```
3200
34300
1499
12899
```

I want to convert these into:

```
32.00
343.00
14.99
128.99
```

How can I achieve this elegantly under PHP using no regex?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$new_array=array();
foreach($old_array as $value)
{
   $new_array[]=number_format(($value/100),2);
}
```

See [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) if you want to fiddle with the thousands separator or something. See [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) if you want to modify the array values in place.

Comment: Useful for Amazon Advertising Products API that returns an Object where the price is formatted without any decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you like anonymous functions and PHP 5.3:

```
$nums = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
array_walk($nums, function (&$val, $key) {
    $val = number_format($val/100, 2);
});
print_r($nums);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.00
    [1] => 2.00
    [2] => 3.00
    [3] => 4.00
)
```

Still and all, the answer is the same: use `number_format()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [number_format](http://php.net/number_format).

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
    $array[$i] = number_format($array[$i]/100,2);
    //if you need them as numbers
    $array[$i] = (float) number_format($array[$i]/100,2);
}
```